# Won't login into JSF application with JMeter

Tags: jsf, cookies, jmeter

I have a big problem with this. I implemented almost every answer on this kind of questions.

I know for the thing about regex and viewState, and this is how mine looks - [regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piFsn.png)

And the Cookie Manager is here also - [cookie manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kvIW.png)

In POST request i changed the `javax.faces.ViewState` value into  `${jsfViewState}` .

And the third  Sampler with GET request, which represent the home screen value when im login, returns me on login page.
Really can't find what could be problem anymore. I tried almost everything! Did i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put your Regular Expression Extractor **as a child** of the `1 - /Login.xhtml`request.
2. You don't need to escape quotation marks, you should be rather escaping dots, but in the most recent JMeter versions it is not requred.

   [image: JMeter Viewstate]
3. Depending on your application implementation you may also need to add [JSESSIONID](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/07/understanding-jsessionid.html) as a part of your URL

I would recommend using

- [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to double check `${jsfViewState}` variable value
- Using "RegExp Tester" mode of the View Results Tree listener to test your regular expression against live data

As a last resort you can consider using an alternative way of recording a JMeter test. It is a cloud-based proxy which can automatically detect dynamic values and perform correlation for you, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Comment: What i exactly should put into Regular Expression Extractor as a regular expression? Should i put `<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState value="([^"]+)".*/>` like i founded in this document [http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter] , or replace `value` with some exact value? I don't understand on base what i should know waht to put into Regular Expression?

Comment: You should be looking into response from `1 - /Login.xhtml` request. If it has redirects you may need to [change your Regular Expression Extractor scope to Main sample and sub-samples](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) so Regular Expression Extractor could look in "child" responses as well

Comment: still have the java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException      http://prntscr.com/cs3vim

Comment: It seems that something isn't good with value of ViewState in Regular Expression Extractor. Is this input good `<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState value="([^"]+)".*/>` , maybe i should change `value` on the end